# Conflict between GAC and Bin dll

Tags: dll, gac, conflict

I'm customizing a SharePoint application, and I am referencing in my Visual Studio project a dll that also exists in the GAC.  The project builds just fine, but when I hit the page I get the following error:

An error occurred during the processing of . c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\bef9a111\5466e63c\App_Web_welcomelinks.aspx_-1775745042.a7euki4f.0.cs(128): error CS0433: The type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing\12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\bef9a111\5466e63c\assembly\dl3\4f0b8d4e\c81e2802_6788c901\PPM.DLL'

Any ideas on how to resolve this conflict?  I can't uninstall the dll from the GAC due to some dependencies, and I can't build my project without the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try stopping IIS, then deleting everything in your 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files' folder then start IIS again.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the reference's Copy Local property to false so that the VS Studio doesn't output a copy of the dll.  That way the CLR will only hit the GAC version.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently cLeaning the project does not automatically delete the files in Bin folder. I went crazy trying to figure it.So if the solution above still doesn't work try to delete everthing inside your project bin folder

Comment: Same here. I just did a search for all the DLLs I wanted to toss from the parent solution folder (in my case "v20" of DevExpress) and after I deleted those, Cleaned and Rebuilt I was back up and running.